# How can I trim the height of UILabel to perfectly fit the text without ever changing font size?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

Here is my UILabel (defined by what is in the yellow):
[image]

Here is after I add **[shortDescriptionLabel sizeToFit];** to end of my code:
[image]

Here is a second example (to show that the font size is actually getting changed after sizeToFit:
[image]

Here is after I add [shortDescriptionLabel sizeToFit]; to end of my code (it is clear that the font size reverted back to size 30.0):

[image]

I would like to trim the excess height (above and below carrots). How can I do this? Here is my current code:

```
    shortDescriptionLabel = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(itemImageView.frame.origin.x+itemImageView.frame.size.width+10, 20, self.tableView.frame.size.width-itemImageView.frame.origin.x-  itemImageView.frame.size.width-20-20, tableViewCellHeight/2)];
    shortDescriptionLabel.text = itemObject.shortDescription;
    shortDescriptionLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:30];
    shortDescriptionLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    shortDescriptionLabel.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = YES;
    shortDescriptionLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    shortDescriptionLabel.minimumScaleFactor = 0;
    [shortDescriptionLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor yellowColor]];
    CGFloat fontSize = shortDescriptionLabel.font.pointSize;
    NSLog(@"fontSize = %f", fontSize);
```

Keep in mind that the last NSLog will always display 30.0 (the font size set earlier) even if the displayed font size is obviously smaller than 30.0.

Please help. There seems to be a lot about this online but I can't seem to get anything to work.

Comment: When are you calling `sizeToFit`?

Comment: I tried adding the line at the end of everything.

Comment: Show what the label looked like after calling `sizeToFit`. Make sure the text has not newlines or other whitespace.

Comment: maddy I have added what it looks like as well as provided a second example. I should have mentioned that it is a multiline UILabel.

Answer (score 0):

Yoh can use `sizeToFit` but if you want to trim the height and keep the width you can add a height constraint equal to the used UIFont's `lineHeight`.

Answer (score 0):

**AutoLayout**

1-Properly Add its Leading,Trailing,Top and bottom Constraints and Write this line of code will do

```
[label setPreferredMaxLayoutWidth:300.0];
```

**Non AutoLayout**

```
-(CGSize)m_GetHeight:(NSString*)text 
{
   CGSize constraintSize=[text sizeWithFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Arial" size:15.] constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(182, 2000) lineBreakMode:NSLineBreakByWordWrapping];
   return constraintSize;

}
```

Comment: I'm not really sure what setting a max width would do. I am worried about the height :S

Comment: When you will assign maxwidth then it will auto adjust its height according to its content size.

Comment: The problem is not my width though. As you can see in the example the width never exceeds where it shouldn't be.

Comment: are you using autolayout ?